# dotnet-ef still not found after installation

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I installed the `dotnet-ef` tool on a Ubuntu server, and it installed successfully. However, the program was still not found:

```
~/app$ dotnet --version
3.1.201
~/app$ dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.3
Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you will need to logout or restart your session before running the tool you installed.
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '3.1.3') was successfully installed.
```

After rebooting the server:

```
~/app$ dotnet-ef migrations add "First On Server"
dotnet-ef: command not found
~/app$ which dotnet
/usr/bin/dotnet
~/app$ which dotnet-ef
~/app$
```

How do I get the `dotnet-ef` tool on a Ubuntu machine?

Comment: The command is `dotnet ef`, not `dotnet-ef`. No `-` here: `dotnet ef migrations ...`

Comment: The installation output says: `You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-ef`.  Anyway, `dotnet ef` also says `specified command not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dotnet tool install` command requires elevation!